# Error in SQL syntax, even tho. everything seems to be normal

Tags: mysql, wampserver

I have been trying to figure out whats wrong for quite long time yet I fail.

The error I get is

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UNSIGNED CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL, `Date' at line 1

I cant seem to figure out whats wrong and this error seems to be quite common. Im not experienced with mysql, nor php for that matter.

Here is a screenshot, this is everything I enter:

[image]

Im unable to post pictures as my reputation is below 10, so please just check the link.

Update #1:

[image]

(I have also tried picking nothing typing null, picking null typing nothing and these with that tickbox on and off)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That UI is nuts... Remove the 'unsigned' option for the 'text' column.

-- Update --

If you were to create the same table manually:

```
create table `Win` (
    `No` int(4) unsigned auto_increment collate utf8_unicode_ci,
    `Text` text(1000) null default null collate utf8_unicode_ci,
    `Date` timestamp default on update current_timestamp collate utf8_unicode_ci,
    index(`No`),
    index(`Text`),
    index(`Date`),
    primary key(`No`)
) engine=InnoDB default charset=utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Take a look at [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php), I haven't used it in years, but when I did it was a great GUI tool for administering MySQL schemas. You may also want to look at [MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/).

Comment: This is fixes the error I have posted, however, it says "#1067 - Invalid default value for 'Text'" for "NULL" default value so I cant just null it, when I just try to set it to "something" then it says "#1101 - BLOB/TEXT column 'Textx' can't have a default value", then if I pick "none" I get "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(50) on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, PRIMARY KEY' at line 1", what should I do ?

Comment: If you want the `Text` column to be NULL, it looks like you have to set a value in the textbox below it. First make sure that box is empty, if that doesn't wory try adding NULL, with any luck it will be the mysql equivalent of `NULL default NULL`.

Comment: Which gets me to; "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(50) on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, PRIMARY KEY' at line 1"

Comment: You added the word NULL to the textbox under the 1000 textbox?

Comment: Can you take another screenshot of what you have and update post?

Comment: Try setting the `Text` column default to 'None', then select the 'Null' checkbox.

Comment: Done, still same. are there any alternative to this UI ? or wampserver if anything to fix this ?

Comment: Best alternative is to create the table manually. You have access to the msyql cli?

Comment: Yes. But I have no idea how to do it manually and this UI supposed to create lines for me is failing. I think Im gonna sleep now and learn how to use that command line stuff tomorrow. If you can link some good tutorials it'd be great, it seems like google has everything and no false info about basic command line stuff anyway --- Anyway thanks for help, I have set your answer as best. Thank you!

Comment: No problem. I updated post with a manual example, as well as some links to other apps which may work for you.

Answer (score -1):

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ') NOT NULL , `product_quantity` INT(5) NOT NULL , `product_image` BLOB NOT NUL' at line 1